# 英語が残っている箇所: プロフィール編集

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

URL: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/edit/nnn

### フォームの見出し

[image: Registered User]

### 保存ボタン付近

[image: Your profile will be updated everywhere.]

### 保存オプションの詳細

[image: Save changes just for this community]

Comment: "Registered User" = 登録されたユーザー. 匿名で質問の登録・回答ができるため、匿名のユーザーは「Unregistered User」が表示されます。そして、仲裁者（モデレーター）がModeratorを表示する。

Comment: 「Register User」意外の翻訳は適用済です。「Registered User」の翻訳は開発者の支援が必要ため、ちょっと時間がかかります。

Comment: うむむ。まだ"Registered User"と出す意図がよくわかりません。登録済みか匿名かによって、ユーザーの行動が変わることがあるのでしょうか? モデレーターの場合は、変なことを書かないようにしよう、など気を使うだろうとは想像できます。
それから、ここでの翻訳はサイト内の他の箇所でも表示されるのでしょうか? プロフィール編集に特化した訳にすると、他の箇所では変な訳になってしまうかもしれません。

Comment: 今プロフィール編集画面を見ると、Registered Userは"FriendlyName(u.UserTypeId)"と表示され、"Save and copy changes to all Stack Exchange communities"は翻訳が反映されていませんでした。

Comment: 質問の中に記載していた翻訳文を、回答として下に抜き出しました

Comment: 今「Save and copy...」が英語でまだ表示されています。

Comment: @AndrewT. http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/1415/30 の報告が[meta-tag:status-planned]なので、そのうち修正されるはずと思います

Answer (score 2):

> Registered User

これは英語自体、ここを"Registered User"としている意図がわかりませんでした。「ユーザー情報」「登録情報」でしょうか。

> Your profile will be updated everywhere. If you want, you can customize your profile just on this community.

登録しているネットワークサイトすべてのプロフィールに変更が反映されます。このコミュニティ上のプロフィールだけ更新することもできます。

> Save changes just for this community

このコミュニティにだけ反映

> Save and copy changes to all Stack Exchange communities

すべての Stack Exchange コミュニティに反映